# Making an input field that is not required to submit the form in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have made this 'transfer money' form that works well, but there is a comment section, and unless I fill that out too, my does not submit and the page simply updates.

How do I fix this?

**MainController.php**

```
public function transfer_money(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        "amount" => 'string',
        'recepitent' => 'string',
        "comment" => 'string'
    ]);
    
    $recepitent = User::where('name', $data['recepitent'])->get()[0]->id;
    $sender = User::where('name', $request->user()->name)->get()[0]->id;
    $recepitentid = User::find($recepitent);
    $senderid = User::find($sender);
    
    if ($senderid->balance >= $data['amount']) {
        $senderid->balance -= $data['amount'];
        $recepitentid->balance += $data['amount'];
        $senderid->save();
        $recepitentid->save();
    } else {
        dd(1);
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/account/transfer', [MainController::class, 'transfer_money']);
```

**transfer.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="transfer">
  @csrf
  <div class="section dark-bg">
    <div class="flex flex-row vert-center horiz-center">
      <input name="amount" class="borderless-input" id="amountinput" placeholder="Enter amount..." autocomplete="off" onkeypress='validate(event, this)'>
    </div>
    <p class="h2 mt mb10">Choose recepitent...</p>
    <select name="recepitent" id="recepitent-s" class="recepitent-select w100">
      @foreach($names as $name1) @if($name1->name != $currentname)
      <option>{{$name1->name}}</option>
      @endif @endforeach
    </select>
    <p class="h2 mt mb10">Payment purpose...</p>
    <textarea name="comment" class="text-input w100" maxlength="99" onkeypress="countChars(this, 'counter1', 100)"></textarea>
    <p class="right" id="counter1">100</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <button id="" class="anchor-button w100" type="submit">send money</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please disable javascript temporarily. Does it submit the form then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to the JavaScript you have onkeypress in the comment field. Otherwise, if you use the nullable rule for the field, the field will be optional and not required for the form submission.

```
public function transfer_money(Request $request) {
    $data = request()->validate([
        "amount" => 'required|string',
        'recepitent' => 'required|string',
        "comment" => 'nullable|string'
    ]);
```